# What is the difference between User permission and Friends permission on Facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

I'm trying to decide which Read Permission to ask for from my users. What exactly am I getting from User permission and from Friends permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User permission is permission to get data about the current logged in user.  Friend permissions are permission to get data about the current logged in users friends.

Comment: But it's just "basic information" right? Just stuff that the friend wouldn't have to approve for?

Comment: You can get whatever is listed on that permission list (videos, checkins, etc) about the friend, but the individual friend privacy settings may override that and so it would return empty for that user.